# Existing image field is not appearing in views

Tags: views, entities, 8

I am having a trouble with displaying existing image field of article content type in views. 
It's not coming while adding a field in views to display.

I am using drupal-8.1.x, also I have tried to upgrade the drupal to it's latest version but it didn't worked.

Comment: _It's not coming while adding a field in views to display._ I would elaborate further on this statement. It's not clear what the problem other than an image field is not displaying (there's no way someone can troubleshoot that based on the limited information here).

Comment: Ok, when I am adding field in views by going fields > add > then searching for image field(which it should be display) but it's not coming.

Comment: So the issue is the article's image field isn't in the list of fields to select in the Views UI?

Comment: @ShawnConn Exactly!